# Create user on Keycloack from curl command

Tags: curl, keycloak

Currently I try to create a user from curl command via Keycloak's Admin REST API.
I can authenticate myself as an admin, I have a good answer, but when I want to create a user, I have an error like: "404 - Not Found".

Here are my curl commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "* Request for authorization"
RESULT=`curl --data "username=pierre&password=pierre&grant_type=password&client_id=admin-cli" http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token`

echo "\n"
echo "* Recovery of the token"
TOKEN=`echo $RESULT | sed 's/.*access_token":"//g' | sed 's/".*//g'`

echo "\n"
echo "* Display token"
echo $TOKEN

echo "\n"
echo " * user creation\n"
curl   http://localhost:8080/apiv2/users -H "Authorization: bearer $TOKEN"   --data '{"firstName":"xyz","lastName":"xyz", "email":"demo2@gmail.com", "enabled":"true"}'
```

I used the official API documentation, located at this address: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/4.4/rest-api/index.html

[image]

I have this error:
[image]

my realm is good
[image]

How I can fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried via Postman. Is the same error received on postman also?

Comment: postam or curl, is the same things except the GUI

Comment: Oops. My bad...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try this, I added the content type header and modify the url :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "* Request for authorization"
RESULT=`curl --data "username=admin&password=Pa55w0rd&grant_type=password&client_id=admin-cli" http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token`

echo "\n"
echo "* Recovery of the token"
TOKEN=`echo $RESULT | sed 's/.*access_token":"//g' | sed 's/".*//g'`

echo "\n"
echo "* Display token"
echo $TOKEN

echo "\n"
echo " * user creation\n"
curl -v http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/apiv2/users -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: bearer $TOKEN"   --data '{"firstName":"xyz","lastName":"xyz", "email":"demo2@gmail.com", "enabled":"true"}'
```

Comment: Note that i had to add the field "username" in order for this to work. Which is marked optional in the docs, but including it is the only difference between 200 ok and 500 "unknown error" version 7.1

Comment: @Kilian would you know how to do this via the admin cli?

Comment: @Saturnian sorry I don't, I haven't work on keycloak since years, but you can check here maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56743109/keycloak-create-admin-user-in-a-realm

Comment: You can also use a POST request instead of GET. I like to use jq to extract values from JSON. Password is stored in a file.
```TOKEN="$(curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "username=admin&password=$(< ./secret/kc-admin-password.txt)&grant_type=password&client_id=admin-cli" http:/localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token | jq -r ".access_token")"```

Answer (score 4):

According to Keycloak's documentation ( [Server Admin > The Admin CLI > Basic operations and resource URIs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#basic-operations-and-resource-uris) ), the `users` endpoint should be:

`http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/apiv2/users`

So please fix your last URL accordingly.

You can also find a full example on [Keycloak's JIRA issue #5383](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-5383). Note that it is adding the content-type header explicitly as well:

`Content-Type: application/json`