# Create a User on Keycloack including password from curl command

Tags: curl, jira, keycloak, jira-rest-api, keycloak-services

I have tried to create a user(without giving any password while creating) on keycloak using CURL command, it's success, but not able to know the password to login.
So, how to give password to a user while creating.
and also how to set default password for new users in keycloak

I have used this link to create a user using curl: [Create user on Keycloack from curl command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440546/create-user-on-keycloack-from-curl-command)

Answer (score 65):

You need to set `credentials` for the user, so that you can login.
something like this

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/apiv2/users -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: bearer $TOKEN"   --data '{"firstName":"xyz","lastName":"xyz", "username":"xyz123","email":"demo2@gmail.com", "enabled":"true","credentials":[{"type":"password","value":"test123","temporary":false}]}'
```

You can also use cli command present in bin directory for creating users

```
add-user-keycloak.sh --user <USER_NAME> --password <PASSWORD>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, i have tried this earlier but no use. User created but not with password.

Comment: I am able to create user using above curl command in master realm and able to login though UI with same credentials. Have you set temporary to false?

Comment: Yes, when i have added a user using "add-user-keycloak.sh --user <USER_NAME> --password <PASSWORD>" 
But i have to do the same with curl.
Thanks again