# Keycloak PUT-request returns 401 (unauthorized)

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I am using postman and I've tried updating a user's profile via http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/demo/users/{userID} but I received a `401` response.

The procedure I used:

- Requested and received admin token via http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
- Added token to request headers the appropriate way i.e Authorization: Bearer {access_token}
- Sent Put request with Json content type and the user's info as body via http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/demo/users/{userID}.

Unfortunately, I've received back-to-back 401 responses.

First request:

-Body(x-www-form-urlencoded)

```
client_id : admin_cli
username: ...
password: ...
grant_type: password
client_secret: ...
```

-To `http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token`

Second request:

-Header -> Authorization: Bearer ...

-Body(JSON)

```
"email": "d@gmail.com",
"firstName": "divad",
"lastName": "d"
```

-To `http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/demo/users/{userID}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** The `/auth` path was removed starting with [Keycloak 17 Quarkus distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902419/1366871). So you might need to remove the `/auth` from the endpoint calls presented on this answer.

---

In your first call, the `david` user has to be one with *admin-alike* privileges. Otherwise, one gets an authorized error response for the actions that the `david` user does not have the privileges to perform. Have a look at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56743109/keycloak-create-admin-user-in-a-realm) to check how to assign *admin-alike* privileges to a user.

For now let us request a token on the behalf of the *master* admin user as follows:

[image]

from the body response extract the `access_token`.

For the second call first, copy and paste the `access_token` to the `Authorization > Type Bearer Token`:

[image]

On the second call, instead of

```
http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/demo/users/{userID}
```

you need to replace the `userID` parameter with the actual `userID` of the user that you are updating. To get `userID` you can call the following endpoint:

```
GET <YOUR_KEYCLOAK_DOMAIN>/auth/admin/realms/<YOUR_REALM>/users/?username=<THE_USERNAME>
```

or you can copy and paste from the Keycloak Admin Console, under the tab users:

[image]

So in Postman would look like:

[image]