# how to use keycloak in django rest framework with custom authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, keycloak, grpc-python

A better title for this question would be: how to use keycloak in django grpc framework.

I want to handle user registration with keycloak. this is the my service without keycloak:

```
class UserService(Service):
    def Create(self, request, context):
        serializer = UserProtoSerializer(message=request)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        # some code for sending activation email
        return serializer.message
```

and I'm using a custom user.
I have created a realm and client in keycloak admin console. what is the best way of relating these two? shall I try using [drf-keycloak-auth](https://pypi.org/project/drf-keycloak-auth/) or [python-keycloak](https://pypi.org/project/python-keycloak/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with a custom authentication it's better to use [python-keycloak](https://pypi.org/project/python-keycloak/) . you can create a user object both in keycloak and your database and save different information about user in them.

the documentation is almost clear if you have followed the steps in [keycloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-docker). the thing I couldn't quite understand was input arguments for keycloak_admin.create_user to create a new user in a realm named 'test'. this the confusing code in documentation:

```
keycloak_admin = KeycloakAdmin(server_url="http://localhost:8080/auth/",
                               username='example-admin',
                               password='secret',
                               realm_name="master",
                               user_realm_name="only_if_other_realm_than_master",
                               client_secret_key="client-secret",
                               verify=True)
```

now the thing you should know before jumping from keycloak documentations to python-keycloak documentations is that you should give one user in your new realm administration role. [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56760280/10829708).

```
keycloak_admin = KeycloakAdmin(server_url="http://localhost:8080/auth/",
                               username='test@user.com',
                               password='123',
                               realm_name="test",
                               verify=True)
```

to generate client secret check: https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_admin/topics/clients/oidc/confidential.html